# wscanw(); not returning string with ncurses.h

Tags: c, windows, input, console, ncurses

When i input "/quit" it does nothing?
I am using PDCurses and MinGW
I am compiling with gcc -o file.exe file.c -lpdcurses

```
    while (1)
    {
        wscanw(inputwin, "%s", &text);
        if (text == "/quit")
        {
            mvwprintw(txtwin, 1, 1, "quit");
            wrefresh(txtwin);
        }
        wrefresh(inputwin);
        wclear(inputwin);
        wrefresh(inputwin);
        wmove(inputwin, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare strings in C with the equality operator since you would compare the pointers addresses rather than the pointed-to values. You should, instead, use [strcmp(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp). Note that strcmp returns 0 when the strings match. Another thing of note. Assuming “text” is pointer to characters then you should not pass it’s address since wscanw would read to the incorrect address. If, however, text is a char then reading into it with wscanw will also invoke undefined behaviour since you’re trying to cram a bunch of characters into a 1 byte region of memory. In this case you could declare text to be an array with proper size or allocate memory with [malloc(3) and friends](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it answered your question